# flip bytes using Python's struct module

Tags: python, struct, endianness, flip

I would like to flip from big to little endian this string:

`\x00\x40`

to have it like this:

`\x40\x00`

I guess the proper function to use would be struct.pack, but I can't find a way to make it properly work.
A small help would be very appreciated !

Thanks

Answer (score 6, accepted):

You're not showing the whole code, so the simplest solution would be:

```
data = data[1] + data[0]
```

If you insist on using `struct`:

```
>>> from struct import pack, unpack
>>> unpack('<H', '\x12\x13')
(4882,)
>>> pack('>H', *unpack('<H', '\x12\x13'))
'\x13\x12'
```

Which first unpacks the string as a little-endian unsigned short, and then packs it back as big-endian unsigned short. You can have it the other way around, of course. When converting between BE and LE it doesn't matter which way you're converting - the conversion function is bi-directional.

Answer (score 5):

`data[::-1]` works for any number of bytes.

Comment: I think this is a much better way to do it.

Answer (score 0):

`little_endian = big_endian[1] + big_endian[0]`

Answer (score 0):

I could image that what would really want to do here is to convert the input data from big endian (or network) byteorder to your host byteorder (whatever that may be).

```
>>> from struct import unpack
>>> result = unpack('>H', '\x00\x40')
```

This would be a more portable approach than just swapping, which is bound to fail when the code is moved to a big endian machine that would not need to swap at all.